# Passing variables from controller to the view is giving error

Tags: laravel

I'm passing multiple variables from the controller to the view via Compact(), 3 of the variables are accessible on view and the rest are giving an error "Undefined variable: ". Is there a limit on passing variable to the view with compact() or with()?

````
 ```
 CONTROLLER:

  class HomePageController extends Controller
{
  public function ShowAdminHomePage()
   {
  $homesection1 = HomeSection1::all();
  $homesection2 = HomeSection2::all();
  $homesection3 = HomeSection3::all();
  $h_s3title = HomeSection3Title::all();
  $count_s1 = HomeSection1::count();
  $count_s2 = HomeSection2::count();
  $count_s3 = HomeSection3::count();
  return view::('backend.page.home.index')->with($homesection1,$homesection2,$homesection3,$count_s1,$count_s2,$count_s2,$count_s3);
  return view('backend.page.home.index', compact('homesection1','homesection2','count_s1','count_s2','homesection3','h_s3title'));
}
 ```


 ```
 VIEW:

   @foreach ($homesection3 as $s3)
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3 mt-30">
              <div class="feature-box bg-white shadow-hover border-radius-3 f-style-5 h-100 icon-grad">
                  <div class="feature-box-icon"><i class="ti-panel"></i></div>
                  <h3 class="feature-box-title">{{$s3->name}}</h3>
                  <p class="feature-box-desc">{{ $s3->description }}</p>
              </div>
          </div>
        @endforeach
 ```
````

I'm able to get the data of $homesectio1, $homesectio2, $count_s1 and $count_s2, but $homesection3 and $h_s3title are giving an error: Undefined variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no limit on php `compact`.

I suggest that you keep the last return statement, the  make sure you do not have any typos in adding the variables to compact or when trying to use it in the view. Also check that the code in the view that precedes the part use $homesection3 is setup correctly.

Comment: I was working on project for about 10 hours. I was working on the controller. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You **`send with compact`** You should set keys and values like this:

```
    return view('backend.page.home.index', compact(['homesection1'=>$homesection1,
                                                    'homesection2'=>$homesection2,
                                                    'count_s1'=>$count_s1,
                                                    'count_s2'=>$count_s2,
                                                    'homesection3'=>$homesection3,
                                                    'h_s3title'=>$h_s3title]);
```